# Adding exponents in algebra?

Tags: polynomials

When simplifying an equation such as $x^4 + x^4$, I know the answer is $2x^4$, but what I don't understand is why don't you add the exponents along with the $x$? $x^4$ is $x \cdot x \cdot x \cdot x$, right? So why can't you simplify/add them, and have the answer be $2x^8$?

Comment: You are familiar with how $x + x = 2x$ I hope... yes?  Well.. we didn't increase the exponent there either, so why would we for your example?  By renaming $x^4$ as $y$ instead, we have $x^4 + x^4 = y + y = 2y = 2(x^4)$.  You are for whatever reason trying to simultaneously multiply and add when we are only adding.  It is when you multiply that the exponent would increase...

Comment: You are dealing with two entirely separate binary operations, one being addition, the other multiplication.

Comment: Do not confuse $x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x \color{red}{+}x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x$ with $x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x \color{red}{\times}x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x$

Comment: A different look at JMoravitz' first comment: $x$ can be anything. Let's say it stands for "a foot" (as in a unit of length, use "a meter" if so inclined). When you add $x+x$, you put two sticks together, length one foot each. The result is a longer stick, length two feet. That is, $2x$. You don't suddenly get $2x^2$, in other words "two square feet". That would be a surface area, and totally absurd. Same with your question except that it's kinda difficult to think what "a foot to the fourth" would stand for.

Comment: Anyway, when adding $x^2+x^2$ you put together two tiles (say), 1 square foot each. The result is a bigger tile of area "two square feet". $2x^4$ would again be some weird 4-dimensional measure.

Answer (score 0):

For example, $2^{4} + 2^{4}$ would not equal $2(2)^{8}$.